# How check all Checkbox items in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

salam
How check all Checkbox items(setMultiChoiceItems) in Android AlertDialog

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(A);
    builder.setTitle(A.getString(R.string.which_number));
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_mini);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(line, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can it help you?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(A);
    builder.setTitle(A.getString(R.string.which_number));
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_mini);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(line, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
                    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
                    ListView v = dialog.getListView();
                    int i = 0;
                    while(i < line.length) {
                        v.setItemChecked(i, check);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Good answer but 1- at the first need to check one box to enable all box checked(need to be out of onclick but how?) 2- after all box checked cant unchecked any of them(we can use a flag (only the first time) to resolve this one)

Comment: It only an example. I will try to refactor it soon.

Answer (score 1):

answer is very simple

the second input parameter of setMultiChoiceItems is default CheckBoxes  status

```
    int L = line.length;
    boolean[] b2 = new boolean[L];
    for(int i=0 ; i<L ; i++){
        b2[i]=true;
    }
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(line, b2,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
```

Comment: How to check the specific items from the list?