# How to check all checkboxes by using Alert Dialog box?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using an alert dialog (setmultichioceitems()), and i am using a button when user click on it, all check-boxes are marked automatically.
but what to write inside markall button so that all checkboxes are checked by just single click.
Here is my code.

```
     AlertDialog.Builder attendance = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     attendance.setTitle("MARK ATTENDANCE");
     attendance.setIcon(R.drawable.markattendeanceicon);

     attendance.setMultiChoiceItems(l, A, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked)
         {
             TastyToast.makeText(AdminPanel.this,"attendance marked of "+l[position],TastyToast.SUCCESS,TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


         }

    }
   });

     attendance.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

             TastyToast.makeText(AdminPanel.this,"your record is saved",TastyToast.INFO,TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
     });
     attendance.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

             dialogInterface.dismiss();
         }
     });

     attendance.setNeutralButton("MarkAll", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

         }
     });

     attendance.setCancelable(false);
     attendance.show();
```

Comment: what you have tried ?please show your code

Comment: where is your checkbox? i means in list or static views?

Comment: my checkbox in list views

Comment: you can use `sharedpreferences` for such purpose. when you click the dialog button to select all check box. take a `boolea`n variable and make it as `tru`e. now inside your activity override a method `onWindowFocusChanged` and check that 

    if(hasfocus){
        // get the boolean from sharepreference
        if(boolean variable == true){ 
            // allcheckboxes.setchecked(true);
           }
    }

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23960860/3111083

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sharedpreferences` for such purpose. When you click the dialog button to select all check box. Take a `boolean` variable and make it as `true`.

```
attendance.setNeutralButton("MarkAll", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             // put sharedprefence value as true/false or 0/1
             SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
             editor.putBoolean("checkboxes", true);
             editor.commit();

         }
     });
```

Now inside `activity` where you have all `checkboxes` call an `override` method.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
       if(hasfocus){
          SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkboxes", defaultMethod);

             if(isChecked){
                  allcheckbox.setChecked(true);
                }
           }
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }
```